# document.deleteElement()?

Tags: javascript, dom, element

For some reason, I create a temporal HTML element using `document.createElement()`. The element is not appended to the document tree. I make a new element every `mousemove()`. Does that allocate any type of memory that I need to deallocate when I am done with the element? How?

Comment: Why do you create a new element on every mouse move?

Comment: As long as there are no references to it (in closures, arrays, or anything), then it should be garbage collected after the function ends.

Comment: I create a canvas to test intersection of mouse with the pixels of an image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't add the element to the DOM or keep any other references to it, they will be freed by the garbage collector. There's no need to manually destroy them.